# W3C validator complaining about duplicate div

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I use a `clear` div in several places in a single HTML file, a la:

```
#clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

usage:

```
<div id="clear">
</div>
```

But W3C's HTML5 validator appears to be complaining that each subsequent use after the initial use is a "duplicate ID":

[image: le validation errors]

Why isn't this valid? How are you supposed to use `clear` divs multiple times on a single page if it isn't technically valid?

Note: this is mostly just an informative question, my HTML renders fine on all modern browsers, and given that this is the only error the HTML5 validator can find, I don't reall care, but I'd just like to know why this is considered to be a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In HTML, [id](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id) attributes must be unique within the whole document. If you want several clear `<div>` elements, use a [class](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-class) instead:

```
.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

---

```
<div class="clear">
</div>
```

Comment: @David, interesting, I wasn't aware of that. Links updated, thanks for the goof list :)

Comment: Thanks - this makes perfect sense.

Comment: Why does my page render differently if I use class="clear" instead of id="clear"?

Comment: @unforgiven3, that's probably because it wasn't valid before, so it forced the browser to fall back to quirks mode when rendering. Now that it's valid, the browser can render it in standards mode.

Comment: Hmm - the only problem is that using class="clear" results in a very thin empty strip across the top of my page, about 6 pixels high, I'd guess. Really odd, I know - but as soon as I go back to id="clear", it works fine and looks great. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Because "Duplicate ID clear".

You cannot have more than one element with a specific ID on the web site. Use class instead.

```
.clear {
  /*code here*/
}

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Classes can be repeated as many times you want to, but IDs can only be used once.

Answer (score 1):

An [id](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) uniquely identifies an element and cannot be reused in a single document.

If you want to indicate that multiple elements have something in common, use a [class](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). You will have to modify your CSS to use a [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#class-html).

---

That said, inserting extra elements that do nothing except set clear is ugly and you should probably look at [an alternative technique](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59) I'd suggest `overflow: hidden` in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a *class* attribute.

ID's attribute values are supposed to be [unique within a page](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-id-attribute).

```
<div class="clear">
</div>

.clear
{
    clear: both;
}
```