# Why should not be id repeated?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="full-width">
<div id="wrap><!--contents with fixed width:: 950px--></div>
</div>

<div id="full-width">
<div id="wrap><!--contents with fixed width:: 950px--></div>
</div>

<div id="wrap"><!--contents with fixed width:: 950px--></div>

<div id="wrap"><!--contents with fixed width:: 950px--></div>

<div id="full-width"><!--contents with full width:: 100%--></div>
```

**Key Question**

This works fine, but many coders or say css rule directs that we should not use same id more than one times. So how could I place my markup? And could anyone describe about that we should use only 1 id not more than this which doesn't work?

Comment: use classes instead of Id's..

Comment: It is better to use class rather than id. So instead of having id="full-width" use class="full-width"

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstood but, maybe you should use classes instead of id's?

Comment: Use `class` instead. Like: `<div class="wrap">`.

Comment: There are answers all over the internet to this, did you even both to open Google?!?! Look [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/css-div-id-vs-div-class) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706250/w3c-validator-complaining-about-duplicate-div) for examples - there are plenty more around!

Comment: @C-Link: I've updated my answer to include the question from your comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15566376/1317805

Comment: @C-Link: your question doesn't make much sense. Problems: 1. Looking at the edit history, you seem to have slowly changed it from its original form of "why can't I use the same ID value more than once per page?" to its current form of "How can I achieve this layout?" It's much easier for people to understand, and therefore give useful answers, if you stick to one question. 2. Your English isn't very clear. I understand it's hard when English isn't your first language, and your English is 100 times better than my Nepali, but this is another reason to keep your questions focused on 1 issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like others before me have said, you are using the `id` tag which is a unique identifier. Whereas you should use a `class` to apply styles across multiple elements.

See what the W3C defines an `id` as: (http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

> Element identifiers: the id and class attributes
>
> Attribute definitions
>
> **id** = name [CS] This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name
>   must be unique in a document.
>
> **class** = cdata-list [CS] This attribute
>   assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. Any number
>   of elements may be assigned the same class name or names. Multiple
>   class names must be separated by white space characters.

What's more interesting is that you stated that your example works, and it does in **most browsers**. This doesn't make it valid or even good HTML/CSS it is just that **some browsers pick up on developer's shortcomings** and will render non-standards compliant code as if it were standards compliant.

Here is an example that can never work. As you may know `id` tags can be used for named anchors. E.g.

```
<a href="#content">Jump to content</a>
<div id="content">
  some content
</div>
<div id="content">
  some other content
</div>
```

In this example, which element should the named anchor link to? In most cases I would assume it would go to the first element. However this may not be what the developer wanted.

The `id` element has more uses than just applying styles to elements, the W3C goes on to state:

> The id attribute has several roles in HTML:
>
> - As a style sheet selector.
> - As a target anchor for hypertext links.
> - As a means to reference a particular element from a script.
> - As the name of a declared OBJECT element.
> - For general purpose processing by user agents (e.g. for identifying fields when extracting data from HTML pages into a database,
>     translating HTML documents into other formats, etc.).
> - The class attribute, on the other hand, assigns one or more class names to an element; the element may be said to belong to these
>     classes. A class name may be shared by several element instances.
>
> The class attribute has several roles in HTML:
>
> - As a style sheet selector (when an author wishes to assign style information to a set of elements).
> - For general purpose processing by user agents.

You should write standards compliant code so you know it functions in standards compliant browsers. The results are far more predictable and stable across a wider range of browsers and more likely to work in future versions.

**Edit: In response to OP's comments:**

CSS:

```
.content {
    width: 950px;
    margin: auto; // Assuming you want to centre this
}
```

Whatever you apply the class `.content` to will have a width of 950px. You don't need to set 100% width on the `#top` element as it is a block level div and naturally expands to 100% width.

HTML:

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="navigation" class="content">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="main" class="content">
</div>

<div id="footer" class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know this rules, what I wanted to know is understood by nobody, anyway I'm gonna accept your answer, could you please correct my markup using div in one container for ease of use?

Comment: @C-Link No problem, although I still don't understand what you are asking. You have many `div` elements in your example, what do you want to do to them?

Comment: I want to give top-part, navigation, main-content, footer, etc. within on container but top-part has 100% and inside a div with 950px width and main contents doesn't have 100% but 950px width like this how to markup in one container, for best practices?

Comment: @C-Link See my updated answer, is that what you wanted?

Comment: Anyway I'm helped from your answer, "You don't need to set 100% width on the #top element as it is a block level div and naturally expands to 100% width.", please see my Edit 3 and correct my final markup please.

Comment: @C-Link There is no easier form of markup, if you need that many `divs` you need that many, if you don't you don't. It depends entirely on how you want your webpage to appear and what sort of content it will contain, this is something we can't tell you and you have to discover for yourself. Until then your code is just 4 divs nested inside another div, each uniquely identified, which is perfectly correct if that is what you need.

Comment: Please save your answer .. in case if post is deleted I really dont want to see this aewsome anser deleted

Comment: @NullPonyPointer Yes I have save this answer.

Comment: @NullPonyPointer How do I save it?

Comment: Dont worry .. flexo locked this post so now it cant deleted . And youcan save by click on edid and copy , markdown and sace in pc

Comment: @NullPonyPointer Ah ok thought it was some form of SO operation.

Answer (score 4):

ID's are unique identifiers, and therefore [there should only be 1 per document](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm) (otherwise its not unique).

Replace `id` with `class` and change your CSS to use class selectors instead of ID selectors.

Therefore instead of:

```
#full-width { ... }
#wrap { ... }
```

Use:

```
.full-width { ... }
.wrap { ... }
```

---

For clarity, your markup should then be:

```
<div class="full-width">
<div class="wrap><!--contents with fixed width:: 950px--></div>
</div>

<div class="full-width">
<div class="wrap><!--contents with fixed width:: 950px--></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap"><!--contents with fixed width:: 950px--></div>

<div class="wrap"><!--contents with fixed width:: 950px--></div>

<div class="full-width"><!--contents with full width:: 100%--></div>
```

Comment: Yep, this. id are what they say: identifiers !

Comment: Nice editing skills. I'm sure most of us wouldn't have answered had your original answer contained all of this information rather than just "replace id with class".

Comment: Thank you very much! But I would like to use in one container for ease of use how to use?

Comment: @C-Link I'm not sure what you are asking? You wish to use ID's?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Answer (score 1):

Ya coders say it right you can not define same `ID` more than once because `ID` must be unique.

You can use `class` instead of `ID`

try this

```
<div class="full-width">
<div class="wrap><!--contents with fixed width:: 950px--></div>
</div>

<div class="full-width">
<div class="wrap><!--contents with fixed width:: 950px--></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap"><!--contents with fixed width:: 950px--></div>

<div class="wrap"><!--contents with fixed width:: 950px--></div>

<div class="full-width"><!--contents with full width:: 100%--></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An id *uniquely* identifies an element in a page. Browsers perform a certain amount of error recovery, but things will certainly break when you start using `<label for...>` and JavaScript to get elements out of the DOM based on IDs.

Classes are provided to markup elements which are part of a group. Use them instead.

```
<someElement class="one_class another_class">

.one_class {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`IDs` are [*unique identifiers*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute), uniquely identifying individual elements on a page.

For this situation where you want to have multiple elements all related to eachother you'd use `classes`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes

You'd then style using `.` rather than `#`:

```
<div class="full-width">
   <div class="wrap">...</div>
</div>

div.full-width {
    width:100%;
    ...
}

div.wrap {
    width:950px;
    ...
}
```

> Thank you very much! But I would like to use in one container for ease of use how to use?

Depending on what you're wanting to achieve, you could simply wrap all your `.wrap` elements within one `.full-width` container:

```
<div class="full-width">
    <div class="wrap">...</div>
    <div class="wrap">...</div>
    <div class="wrap">...</div>
    <div class="wrap">...</div>
</div>
```

Or you could just use one `.wrap` element:

```
<div class="full-width">
    <div class="wrap">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I assume you'd also want to horizontally centre your `.wrap` divider:

```
div.wrap {
    width:950px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NaGwL/1/).

Comment: I would like to up vote your answer but previously I was banned when voting up my question's answer after I accepted. Sorry!

Comment: You're saying you can't upvote my answer because you were previously banned for something unrelated? o.o

Comment: Yes! previously I have voted on more than one answer.

Comment: You're allowed to vote on multiple answers... You probably voted too many times in a certain time frame or something.

Comment: Sorry! I don't give you up vote at this time.

Comment: @C-Link - You never get ban because of upvoting answers. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/187824 for more info.

Comment: @hims056 Unless it's for voting irregularities, of course, such as voting for your own sock-puppet or being a bunch of guys from the same office always upvoting each other. =)

Comment: @J.Steen - Hmm but that is called suspension IMO. :)

Comment: @hims056 Suspension, ban, they're all just words. There is obviously a language barrier here, so it's **very** unclear what OP even means. =)

Answer (score 0):

You are repeating in ID for DOM `<div id="full-width"><div id="wrap>` that is wrong.

Use class `<div class="full-width"><div class="wrap>`

Apply `css` to `class` as below.

```
.full-width { /** css code **/ }
.full-width .wrap { /** css code **/ }
.wrap { /** css code **/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply the same style on multiple objects you should use the class attribute. When you use the same id attribute on multiple objects you cannot access a specific object by its id (as it is supposed to by accessed by e.g. `getElementById()`)